# How do I pause my shell script for a second before continuing?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have only found how to wait for user input. However, I only want to pause so that my `while true` doesn't crash my computer.

I tried `pause(1)`, but it says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '1'`. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1972):

Use the `sleep` command.

Example:

```
sleep .5 # Waits 0.5 second.
sleep 5  # Waits 5 seconds.
sleep 5s # Waits 5 seconds.
sleep 5m # Waits 5 minutes.
sleep 5h # Waits 5 hours.
sleep 5d # Waits 5 days.
```

One can also employ decimals when specifying a time unit; e.g. `sleep 1.5s`

Comment: It seems on Mac OS X, the s, m, h, nor d have any impact. You must specify the time in seconds.

Comment: I think the naming is because we have `thread.sleep` function in many programming languages @Geremia

Comment: More recently the suffix gives an error on Mac. "usage: sleep seconds"

Comment: If you get an "invalid time interval" you might want to check for your end of line setting, if you created your script with a Windows tool your end of line is "CR LF", you need to change it for Linux which is "LF" only. (Actually the error should be self explicit: invalid time interval '1\r' here you can see the extra \r from the \r\n)

Answer (score 218):

And what about:

```
read -p "Press enter to continue"
```

Comment: Actually, this answered _my_ question, even if it doesn't answer the OP.

Comment: this has nothing to do with this post.

Comment: @murtadhaalsabbagh, But has very much to do with Google indexing :) Helped me too, btw.

Comment: read -p "Press enter to continue" -t 1 
should pause for 1 sec

Comment: @JesseChisholm I guess people are looking for the bash equivalent of the powershell/cmd `PAUSE`

Answer (score 92):

In Python (question was originally tagged Python) you need to import the time module

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
```

or

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)
```

For shell script is is just

```
sleep 1
```

Which executes the `sleep` command. eg. `/bin/sleep`

Comment: yes, this says it too, it's just the other one was first, and it has a nice example :)    but +1!

Comment: So while not the right way to do it, you can combine the python answer with Bash by using `python -c "import time; time.sleep(1)"` instead of `sleep 1` :)

Comment: @BerryM. - Takes about 1.2 seconds when I try it. Python doesn't start up instantly - you need to account for that. Make it `python -c "import time; time.sleep(0.8)"` instead. But then we need to factor in how long python startup actually takes. You need to run this: `date +%N; python -c "import time; time.sleep(0)"; date +%N` to determine how many nanoseconds python is taking to start. But that also includes some overhead from running date. Run this `date +%N; date +%N` to find that overhead. Python's overhead on my machine was actually closer to 0.14 seconds. So I want `time.sleep(0.86)`.

Comment: True, though you'll never get _exactly_ 1000ms, not even like that.

Answer (score 70):

Run multiple sleeps and commands

```
sleep 5 && cd /var/www/html && git pull && sleep 3 && cd ..
```

This will wait for 5 seconds before executing the first script, then will sleep again for 3 seconds before it changes directory again.

Comment: +1 ... cuz if you use one ampersand after the sleep it sends sleep off to its own thread then immediately starts the next action (i.e. the sleep doesn't delay the next action)

Comment: Why `&&` and not `;`?

Comment: @vrnvorona `&&` will wait for the first command to finish.

Comment: @RobotBoy i think most importantly, if first command fails, && won't proceed, but ; will. ; will wait too, but won't check success.

Answer (score 45):

I realize that I'm a bit late with this, but you can also call sleep and pass the disired time in. For example, If I wanted to wait for 3 seconds I can do:

```
/bin/sleep 3
```

4 seconds would look like this:

```
/bin/sleep 4
```

Comment: I needed this not the python one. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

On Mac OSX, sleep does not take minutes/etc, only seconds. So for two minutes,

```
sleep 120
```

Answer (score 23):

Within the script you can add the following in between the actions you would like the pause. This will pause the routine for 5 seconds.

```
read -p "Pause Time 5 seconds" -t 5
read -p "Continuing in 5 Seconds...." -t 5
echo "Continuing ...."
```

Comment: This wont actually work, will it? I think that `-t 5` will abort the script after 5 seconds, not continue, at [least according to this man page for read](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)

Comment: @BradParks  Yes it will work Just in case:
root@Joses-iPad:~
# cat readtest.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Here"

read -p "Pause Time 5 seconds" -t 5
read -p "Continuing in 5 Seconds...." -t 5
echo "Continuing ...."

echo "There"

root@Joses-iPad:~
# cat re./st.bash 
Here
Pause Time 5 secondsContinuing in 5 Seconds....Continuing ....
There

Comment: Hmmm.... I think you're right! I thought I tried this, but I just tried it again and it works as advertised. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
read -r -p "Wait 5 seconds or press any key to continue immediately" -t 5 -n 1 -s
```

To continue when you press any one button

*for more info check `read` manpage [ref 1](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html), [ref 2](https://ss64.com/bash/read.html)*

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This answer is a code-only comment. It does not attempt to explain the code given. I feel the poster misinterpreted the question as "How do I wait for user input while simultaneously having a timeout on that user input"

Answer (score 3):

You can make it wait using $RANDOM, a default random number generator. In the below I am using 240 seconds. Hope that helps @

```
> WAIT_FOR_SECONDS=`/usr/bin/expr $RANDOM % 240` /bin/sleep
> $WAIT_FOR_SECONDS
```

Answer (score 3):

use `trap` to pause and check command line (in color using `tput`) before running it

```
trap 'tput setaf 1;tput bold;echo $BASH_COMMAND;read;tput init' DEBUG
```

press any key to continue

> use with `set -x` to debug command line

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use software flow control.

```
Ctrl+s Freeze the terminal
Ctrl+q Unfreeze
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control

```
$ while :; do sleep 0.2; echo hello; done
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Use Ctrl+s to pause and Ctrl+q to resume the infinite loop.