# How to start Node.js in specific URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, terminal

When I'm updating (and testing) a specific page in my application, I need to stop the server, start again with `node server.js`, switch to the browser window, hit F5 and switch back to the terminal to see the output. This takes a lot of time.. :)

Is there a way I can start Node with something like this:

```
node server.js -url /my_page
```

so I can directly see the output as if someone hit the page from their browser?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500326/how-to-use-nodejs-to-open-default-browser-and-navigate-to-a-specific-url) but I guess it's included in the server code so it needs to be updated each time too. It is a solution, but I wonder if there is a faster way to do this.

Thanks,

### Edit:

With curl, I'm getting this error:

```
$ node server.js & curl 'http://localhost:5000/my_page'
[2] 12824
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
[1]   Terminated              node server.js
$ Listening on port 5000
```

Notice the last line, is it executing `curl` before the server is started?

Comment: @OrangeDog yay! it seems to be working. I'm getting an error but I think it's related to the code inside my_page. You might consider posting this as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Should I use `&&` in Ubuntu?

Comment: No: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
node server.js & curl 'http://localhost/my_page'
```

This starts the server in the background, then immediately uses [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) to make an HTTP request.

The server will still be running after this. You can bring it to the foreground (e.g. in order to kill it) with [`fg`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins). Alternatively just run the two commands (without [`&`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)) in separate terminals (or [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)s).

If the server doesn't start fast enough, just [add a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21620406/476716):

```bash
node server.js & sleep 1 ; curl 'http://localhost/my_page'
```

Comment: OK. So the `EADDRINUSE` error was because the previous instances were still open. Thanks so much for your help!