# How to create a .bat file which execute python file

Tags: windows, batch-file, git-bash

I'm new to bat file and started to implementing it. I have a list of linux application commands which starts my application. I have a windows system to deploy, used to git bash to execute those commands, but in every system restart have to start the application manually so I started implementing bat file which mapped in system start up

```
@echo off

title ML_autostart_API
start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"
```

using the above script I've opened the git bash. In further need to perform below commands

```
# To activate python Environment
source E:/ML_APIs/Python_Environment/python3.8.10/Scripts/activate 
# To navigate the project dir
cd E:/ML_APIs/API/Call_SessionV1
# To set the environment variables
source config/config.sh
# To run python application
python application.py
```

have to execute the above using git bash since it is open source commands and doesn't execute in windows. git bash is opening and further commands is not working.

Comment: Any reason you tagged PowerShell?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Just for better reach

Comment: umm, have you tried to pass the second command as a `.sh` file? i didnt see you pass anything to the started git bash. i presume you just put the following command into the same `.bat` file.

Comment: @BagusTesa, I've tried `start "" "C:\Program\ Files/Git/etc/profile"` to navigate to git terminal as per few sources and it won't helped me. I'm completely fresh to this and some insights might welcome

Comment: sorry, let me reword my question, are those `source` called inside `.bat` file after you `start` the `git-bash.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make 2 files, one for the windows command line (`.bat`) another for the `bash` script (`.sh`). The reason being, after you `start` the `bash` console, it will work on different window and it has no idea what your `.bat` contains. We shall call our scripts as `boot.bat` and `start.sh` respectively.

#### boot.bat

```
@echo off

title ML_autostart_API
start "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" start.sh
```

Notice the `start.sh` is added at the end of the `start` command as parameter.

#### start.sh

```
# To activate python Environment
source E:/ML_APIs/Python_Environment/python3.8.10/Scripts/activate 
# To navigate the project dir
cd E:/ML_APIs/API/Call_SessionV1
# To set the environment variables
source config/config.sh
# To run python application
python application.py
```

## Note

- Both scripts are in the same directory.
- This answer assumes `python` is actually recognized in `git-bash` paths.

  Should this is not the case, you can just use the full path to the executable to call it.
- A better alternative would be to just execute the bash script directly on start up (using that `start "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" start.sh`), no mixing stuff.

Comment: How may track whether my commands executing or not like pause in cmd

Comment: @SabarishR, you can use [`sleep 10`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21621163) for 10 seconds delay in `bash`.

Comment: Need to add the same in end of .sh file. Is it

Comment: @SabarishR yes, can use `sleep 10` just like `pause`. though if i remember correctly it only delays the window from closing for 10s after your `python application.py` finishes its job.

Comment: The solution I'm exactly looking for. It works perfectly fine. Thanks!